# add data to firebase realtime if not exists

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

coming from a SQL background I am still getting used to Firebase.
If I have a node for customers and I allow Firebase to create an id by using the "push" method, how do I take a customer and then only push if it doesn't already exist with the same email address and if it does, then update it?
I know set will create or update if I have a specific node (ie each node is identified by, say, the email address) but in this case I want to push if it doesn't exist and presumably set if it does. What's the neatest syntax for doing this?
thanks
Phil

Comment: are you using javascript?

Comment: you will need to use dataSnapshot.exists() to verify if the data exists, and a for loop to loop through all your childrens, and update and create the data with a hashmap

Comment: yes Peter I am using nodejs.
Gaston, I don't understand that answer! do you have a code sample? thanks

Comment: ok, I got it in the end using the exists and then forEach returning true after the first loop. Not using a hashmap as I don't understand what or how....
cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Firestore is recommended for projects going forward. More features.

Note that firebase auth has this email duplication functionality baked in already. So, you might be spending effort on a feature that is already done for you. See [auth/account-exists-with-different-credential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithPopup)

Finally to answer your specific question:
The way I do that is to chain the write after a read (`.then`). The read seeks to fetch the node. After the read if whatever field exists or `=== myString` then you know it's already there.

Comment: thanks Ron, I will look at Firestore but at the moment I am using Firebase. And it will be good for me to understand how to do this in theory even if it is already baked in for this specific case. 
Again, from a SQL background I am not totally au fait with the code to do this - do you have an example where I read the customers node looking for a customer (with autoi-id) which has an email matching my predicate and then either updating that or, having discovered it doesn't exist, pushing it?
thanks

Comment: what I have tried and almost works is this:
   db.ref('customers').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value)
      .then(result=>{
         if (!result.exists()){
            return db.ref('customers').push(myCustomer)
         } else {
            return result.ref.set(myCustomer)
         }
      })
This adds when necessary with an auto id and recognises when an update is necessary but basically it overwrites the customers node removing all existing data and writes the customer data directly to that node, not the specific customer node I wanted it to update

Comment: I changed the else to var promise = null; result.forEach(child=>{promise = db.ref('customers/' + child.key).set(myCustomer);return true;}) return promise;
And that seems to work. Not sure if it's the best way - please advise if it could be neater/more efficient.
Thanks